# how to add predicted column to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, logistic-regression

i am using the following code to predict the value of x. i'd like to add the predicted value/column to the data frame. How to add ?

```
logit.fit<- glm(x~.-y, family = binomial(logit),data = data$train) 
logit.preds <- predict(logit.fit,newdata=data$val,type="response") 
logit.pred <- prediction(logit.preds,data$val$x) 
logit.perf <- performance(logit.pred,"tpr","fpr")
```

data$val is the validation set and data$train is the training set.

Comment: Is `data$val` a data.frame and `logit.pred` a vector with the same number of rows? If so, you can assign a the vector to the data.frame with `data$val$pred <- logit.pred`

Comment: yea data$val is a data frame. i am unsure if they have same number of rows. but i think so. tried assigning but having the error,  Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

Comment: Oh, in that case, I think it must be that `logit.pred` is not a simple vector. (I haven't used `glm` followed by `prediction` recently, if ever.)

Comment: Does `str(logit.pred)` tell you where the data is stored in it? Perhaps you can extract just one component of it to preclude the "S4" error.

Comment: What package do the `prediction` and `performance` functions come from?  Adding the results of `predict.glm` to a data.frame is relatively straightforward, but I don't know what `prediction` does.

Comment: @aosmith it comes form ROCR

Answer (score 1):

The following should be what you are looking for

```
install.packages("broom")
install.packages("ggplot2")

iris$y <- (iris$Species=="setosa")*1
logit.fit<- glm(y ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length, 
            family = binomial(logit), data = iris) 

View(ggplot2::fortify(logit.fit))
View(broom::augment(logit.fit))
```